# How much does it cost to move a furnace from the attic down to the first floor?

Tags: hvac

I have a one story slab home and when I moved in two years ago I had to replace the whole unit. I wasn't even thinking about having them put the unit on the first floor. There is a closet(which is a hall closet) that is right by where I have the wall vent for my air run. I was wondering if I could use that hall closet for the furnace and what else I would have to have done to make it possible to have the furnace on the first floor.

Comment: Think you need to ask some local contractors about this. Maybe even get permit(s) with your town/city to have it inspected afterwards.

Comment: You might get some estimates of varying accuracy here, but the only way to know for sure is to have someone come to the house and give you a quote.

Comment: Shopping/cost related questions are not a good fit for our site because the go out of date soon and are location dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Six Things to Consider:

- Electrical - Generally easy to move
- Natural Gas (if it is a natural gas furnace)
- Output Air - might require one big duct between old and new but there may be alternatives.
- Return Air - similar to Output Air
- Combustion Exhaust
- Connection to air conditioner (if you have one) - typically a couple of pipes for input and output.

Except for electrical, all of these require some real planning to make sure they can be done safely and effectively and at a reasonable price. But hard to guess as variables include:

- type of furnace
- access to old and new locations
- walls between old and new locations

Comment: Not sure why the downvote looks good to me for things to consider+

Comment: @EdBeal Who knows. I've given up trying to guess the downvotes. One possibility though could be "The answer doesn't actually answer the question of 'how much does it cost'". Except that anyone who thinks about it will either do what I did (provide the parameters to consider & to discuss with a contractor) or VTC (which 4 people have apparently done). Can't win!

Comment: I answer off topic questions all the time, I did VTC but think your advice was good. If I see a down vote without any reason I reverse them, a few months back there were quite a few every day not so many lately.